# How to clone JDT ICompilationUnit

Tags: java, eclipse, clone, eclipse-jdt

I need to get a copy (deep clone) from org.eclipse.jdt.core.**ICompilationUnit**. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you need the clone for, [`getWorkingCopy(...)`](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2FICompilationUnit.html&anchor=getWorkingCopy-org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor-) may be the simple answer. But note, that ICompilationUnits, like all IJavaElements are only handles, computing their details only on demand. Thus, a clone will be little more than a new reference to the same underlying structure.

PS: If you use working copies, don't forget to discard them, when no longer needed.